# How to run JOB-2 after JOB-1 when both success and failed

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, devops, cicd

I have a GitLab pipeline with two stages, Stage-1 and Stage-2. In Stage-1, I have two jobs, Job-1 and Job-2. I need Job-2 to run immediately after Job-1, irrespective of whether Job-1 succeeds or fails, and Job-2 should use the artifacts created by Job-1.

In Stage-2, I have Job-1, which I want to run only after Stage-1's Job-1 is completed successfully. How can I set up these dependencies and ensure a smooth flow between the stages and jobs in my GitLab CI/CD pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

> I need Job-2 to run immediately after Job-1,

You can use the `needs:` keyword for creating DAGs of jobs that run immediately once their needed dependencies complete. This works both between stages and within the same stage.

> irrespective of whether Job-1 succeeds or fails

You can use `when: always` to ensure the job will run even if preceding jobs fail.

> Job-2 should use the artifacts created by Job-1.

Artifacts are passed normally, just make sure job-1 is configured to pass artifacts *always* using `artifacts:when:`

> In Stage-2, I have Job-1, which I want to run only after Stage-1's Job-1 is completed successfully

This would simply just be the normal behavior -- jobs in subsequent stages will run after the jobs in the preceding stage are complete. If you want it to start immediately after the dependent job is complete, use `needs:` like described.

So, something like this.

```yaml
stages:
  - one
  - two

job_one_1:
  stage: one
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ...
    when: always  # upload artifacts even on failure

  # ...

job_one_2:
  stage: one
  needs: [job_one_1]  # run immediately after the first job
  when: always  # always run, even if job_one_1 fails
  # ...

job_two_1:
  stage: two
  # optionally, you can uncomment the following line:
  # needs: [job_one_1]
  # ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @sytech, I have already tested this method. When I use always, Job one and job two in stage one will start parallel without waiting.